# Не изменяется тема Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

При редактировании сайта возникла следующая проблема. На сайте Wordpress была установлена пользовательская тема, в которой мне нужно изменить одно изображение. Из файлового менеджера на хостинге скачал это изображение (назовём его image.png), отредактировал необходимое, загрузил новое изображение image_1.png, а в коде темы, в файле стилей, в котором описан внешний вид темы, в месте, где используется исходная картинка, поменял строчку

```
background: url("../images/image.png") no-repeat left top;
```

на строчку

```
background: url("../images/image_1.png") no-repeat left top;
```

После этого сохранил изменения, зашёл ещё раз в файл, чтобы проверить изменения, убедился в их присутствии. Затем зашёл на сайт, но каково было моё удивление, когда я не обнаружил нового изображения.
После этого я удалил исходное изображение, дабы проверить, но подобное не оказало никакого воздействия на сайт. Также я пробовал изменить другие строки кода, но и они не возымели должного эффекта. Какие возможные решения для данной проблемы?

Comment: Кеши. Браузера, серверные, етс

Comment: @SeVlad, заработало. Всё так ужасно просто. А почему Вы не написали это ответом? Я бы смог отметить это как решение. В любом случае, спасибо.